# How to get Json ActionResult into string

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, string

I have a Controller method like below (which I do not want to change):

```
public class UserController : Controller
{

    public ActionResult GetData(......) 
    {

      var  returnData = ......

      ........................
      ........................

      return Json(returnData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
   }
}
```

Now I want to call this above method in a different controller's method & want to get this Json data for some purpose..

```
public class UtilityController : Controller
{

    public ActionResult MyMethod(......) 
    {

      string actionURL = "/User/GetData/123";

      string userDataInString = **???????????????????**

      userDataInString = userDataInString + ".........................";

      return Json(userDataInString , JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

so I want to know how can I call the **GetData** of **UserController** using **actionURL** to assign the **userDataInString**

Comment: Can you in which language this code is written?

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would be to refactor your code to make the current logic in GetData() into it's own function, return the Json from that to the current GetData as Json, then in your new MyMethod() call the re factored method and append it as you described.

```
[NonAction]    
public ActionResult RefactoredGetData(...)
{
   ..............
   ..............
}

public ActionResult GetData(...)
{
   var returnData = RefactoredGetData(...)
   return Json(returnData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}

public string MyMethod(...)
{
   string actionURL = "/User/GetData/123";
   string userDataInString = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(RefactoredGetData(...));
   userDataInString = userDataInString + ".........................";
   return userDataInString;
}
```

Note that because the serializer is returning the data in JSON already you cannot return it with the Json() method as I believe it would further serialize it a second time. So I'm returning it as a plain string in this case. Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: I cann't use this approach  because I don't want to change original getdata method or its controller as I have written my problem in a simple example though actually this getdata is written at various controllers as it got invoked by a user control which can exist at  N number of places, thanks for you answer.

Answer (score 0):

Execute a GET request from the controller with a helper method.

```
public ActionResult MyMethod(......) 
    {

    string controller = "UserController";
    string action = "GetData";
    string query = "123";
    string address = Request.Url.GetLeftPart(System.UriPartial.Authority) + Url.Action(action, controller) + "/" + query;

     string userDataInString = GetRequest(address);//address in place of actionUrl
     userDataInString += ".........";
     return Json(userDataInString , JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
     }

        private string GetRequest(string address)
        {
                WebClient client = new WebClient ();//pick your poisen...
                return client.DownloadString (address);
        }
```

Unless you have a good reason to use a RESTful approach...if you have control of both ends of the request, I recommend you move this into a BL to save on HTTP requests.

---

Json from Cookie

```
private void GetRequestCreateCookie(string address)
{
    var myCookie = new HttpCookie("aCookie");           
    var client = new WebClient();
    myCookie["jsonResponse"] = client.DownloadString(address);
    myCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(1);//some amt of time       

    // Add the cookie.
    Response.Cookies.Add(myCookie);            
}
```

Reading (check for null in a real app)...

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SomeMethod(/*param(s)*/)
    {
        HttpCookie cookie = Request.Cookies["aCookie"];
        string answer = cookie["jsonResponse"];
        //...
     }
```

Comment: It looks fit in my problem, Let me try this.. Thanks.

Comment: How can I set Cookies in GetRequest() ?

Comment: Actually my question is while calling the client.DownloadString ...I want to set something in Cookie beforehand because code checks for a session guid in cookie which I need to set otherwise client.DownloadString will fail.

Comment: @Arun -  Just use the same method for creating a cookie to do that then.